# Extract values of a certain type within a multi-dimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Does anyone know how to extract arrays that of a certain type from a larger array? For example, consider these results from a var_dump():

```
     [0]=>
      array(5) {
        ["post"]=>
        string(60) "Paris"
        ["capacity"]=>
        string(5) "58515"
        ["region"]=>
        string(60) "WHA"
        ["seats"]=>
        string(2) "55"
        ["growth"]=>
        string(4) "3880"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(5) {
        ["post"]=>
        string(60) "Tel Aviv"
        ["capacity"]=>
        string(6) "530910"
        ["region"]=>
        string(60) "NEA"
        ["seats"]=>
        string(2) "65"
        ["growth"]=>
        string(4) "3267"
      }
      [2]=>
      array(5) {
        ["post"]=>
        string(60) "Paris"
        ["capacity"]=>
        string(6) "962115"
        ["region"]=>
        string(60) "EUR"
        ["seats"]=>
        string(2) "11"
        ["growth"]=>
        string(4) "2660"
      }
```

I am sure this may seem simple to some that live in the 5th dimension, but I am having a devil of a time extracting arrays where region = "WHA" within my foreach() to try and build a separate array with just the WHA data.

```
foreach($data as $keys => $datums){
    //Planning to build JSON string
    if($datums['region'] == "WHA"){
        //Some processing
    }
}
```

The result should look like this:

```
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["post"]=>
    string(60) "Paris"
    ["capacity"]=>
    string(5) "58515"
    ["region"]=>
    string(60) "WHA"
    ["seats"]=>
    string(2) "55"
    ["growth"]=>
    string(4) "3880"
  }
```

I have tried all kinds of different things like looking at array_filter that are just not working for me, and I am just concerned about what the right way looks like. Any ideas? Much appreciated.

Comment: I don't really see where you are stuck? You can do it of course like you already do it with a foreach loop and add the array: `if($datums['region'] == "WHA"){ $result[] = $datums; }`. Or also with `array_filter()`, e.g. `$result = array_filter($yourArray, function($v){return $v["region"] == "WHA";});` (btw: I live in the 4th dimension :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I believe you want to build a new array that only contains the elements from the first array that pass a test. The following example does that and produces a JSON encoded string of that data:

```
$new = Array();
foreach($data as $key => $datum){
    //Planning to build JSON string
    if ( $datum['region']=='WHA') {
        $new[] = $datum;
    }
}
$out = json_encode($new);
```

Comment: I used array_push($new, $datums); and got what I wanted as there are many arrays with WHA as the region. I know I was close. Must have been tired :). Thanks for the tip @Octopus.

Comment: array_push($haystack,$needle) does exactly the same as $haystack[] = $needle

Answer (score 1):

Think this should fix your code.

```
foreach($data as $keys => $datums){
    //Planning to build JSON string
    if(isset($datums["region"]) && strcmp($datums["region"], "WHA") === 0){
        //Some processing
     }
 }
```

Comment: Why should OP use double quotes for the array index? Makes no difference if `'` or `"`

Comment: I know it should not matter, but I have had problems with it :)

Comment: You can use the faster `===`  if you don't need to know which string is _greater_. See this [link](http://snipplr.com/view/758/)

Answer (score 1):

You could also encapsulate this in a function

```
<?php
function filterArray($arr, $index, $filter) {
    foreach( $arr as $key=>$elem ) {
        if ( $elem[$index] != $filter ) {
            unset($arr[$key]);
            }
        }
    return $arr;
    }
?>
```

If `$YourArray` is the OP's array, you could use this to filter out any item in the array which does not have an indexed element for "region" which equals "WHA"

```
$filtered = filterArray($yourArray, "region", "WHA");
```

An alternative version of this would use an ampersand (&) to pass a pointer to the original array. For example, if you used this as your function declaration:

```
function filterArray(&$arr, $index, $filter) {
```

then you no longer need to set a destination for the returned array, because the original array actually gets modified directly by the function.

```
filterArray($yourArray, "region", "WHA");
```